# Convert pixels into percentage for all elements of a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, pixel

I have created a webpage that has fixed positions using height, width, left, right position in  elements on the page.

Spent almost 3 days in designing the UI and now I am having issue with different screen resolutions. The page was built with high resolution and if I try it on a low resolution screen it cuts off part of the screen.

Is there a way I can convert all the pixel values on the page to percentages so it adapts the screen resolution of the user?

Comment: maybe you should try to declare min-width and max-width for your elements instead

Comment: and / or mediaqueries ( http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/ )

Comment: @Lollero How do I use that mate?

Comment: The idea is to define parts of the code to change when window width is set to something specific. http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/dBh9D/ and width max-wight http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/dBh9D/1/ - Here's some explanation into media queries http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/ - Here are some examples for devices, but you can just use custom widths if you want to http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/ - You may want to google: Responsive web design

Answer (score 1):

The idea is simple . You need to have containing container with 100% width and all children should add up to have 100% (+/- any padding/border). I have created an example in here

http://jsfiddle.net/fBXkQ/  (you can change the viewport and it will adjust itself )

```
<ul style="width:100%">
   <li style="width:50%"></li>
    <li style="width:50%"></li>

</ul>
```

inline style is just for example but try to not use . Check the fiddle.

Check if that solve your issue . But you might need a min-width set to some value just to make sure it does not shrink below that threshold width.